# Error Alert in the Eclipse Console

Tags: android, sql, database, console

this:

> [2011-01-19 12:25:46 - com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.project.AndroidManifestHelper] Parser exception for C:\Praxiseinsatz\AndroidManifest.xml: Element or attribute do not match QName production: QName::=(NCName':')?NCName.

This the alert I get no matter what I do in my android project.

When I try to start my app I am being given the alert:

> The app has stopped working unexpectedly

and I am going nuts!
I hope you can help me and tell me what to do :(

Answer (score 0):

Productions are rules that specify syntax or "grammar". `QName` is the production for a name or an attribute in a tag, like "activity" in:

```
<activity .... >
    ...
</activity>
```

So there must be an error in one (or more) of them, like not prefixing a needed namespace

(Usually when I get some strange error I copy and paste it in google, in double quotes. I often [find discussions about that](http://www.google.com/search?q=%22Element+or+attribute+do+not+match+QName+production%22&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8).)